# rotate a quadruple in an array

Tags: java, arrays, generics, rotation

Given is an generic Array T[] arr. Every Quadrupel in this Array shall be rotated left, so

> "a b c d e f" --> "b c d a e f"

If the Arrays End isn't a complete Quadrupel, these elements shouldn't rotate.

My Idea was:

```
T[] arr2;

int x;

T temp0 = arr[x+0];

T temp1 = arr[x+1];

T temp2 = arr[x+2];

T temp3 = arr[x+3];

arr2[x+3] = temp0;

arr2[x+2] = temp3;

arr2[x+1] = temp2;

arr2[x+0] = temp1;

x += 1;
```

So I'm switching the Elements of the first Quadrupel and saving them to a second array. 
But how can I implement, that an incomplete Quadruple doesn't rotate, an it stops an the end of the Array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following to process each quad. Note that my code assume that you properly defined arr and arr2;

**This is if you want the results in a new array `arr2`**

```
for(int i = 3; i < arr.length; i += 4) // i is pointing at the end of each quadruple, so it will never show an incomplete one
{
    arr2[i-3] = arr[i-2];
    arr2[i-2] = arr[i-1];
    arr2[i-1] = arr[i];
    arr2[i] = arr[i-3];
}

int nbRemainingElements = arr.length % 4;
for(int i = 0; i < nbRemainingElements; ++i)
{
    int index = arr.length - i - 1;
    arr2[index] = arr[index];
}
```

**This is if you want to modify `arr` without instanciating another array**

```
for(int i = 3; i < arr.length; i += 4) // i is pointing at the end of each quadruple, so it will never show an incomplete one
{
    T firstQuadElement = arr[i-3];
    arr[i-3] = arr[i-2];
    arr[i-2] = arr[i-1];
    arr[i-1] = arr[i];
    arr[i] = firstQuadElement;
}
```

By the way, a solution if you want two different arrays could also be to copy arr using `array.copy` and then apply solution 2

Comment: Thanks!
But with this code, I would only rotate complete Quadruples and ignore the rest of the Array. So how do I find out, how many Elements are following after the last Quadruple and add them to the new arr2?

Comment: Sorry, forgot about that last part. I added it

Comment: I gave two solutions, depending on if you want another array of modify the existing one

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your code inside a loop (which you probably missed in your question)
Please pay attention to:

1. Finish looping early enough NOT to include last unfinished Quadrupel (thus the limit `length-3` which also prevents out of bounds exception, as there is no sense for checking for Quadrupel if only 3 items left.
2. Just copy remaining part of the array as-is

Sample code below:

```
int x = 0;

while(x < arr.length - 3) {
    arr2[x+3] = arr[x+0];
    arr2[x+2] = arr[x+3];
    arr2[x+1] = arr[x+2];
    arr2[x+0] = arr[x+1];
    x +=4;
}

while(x < arr.length) {
    arr2[x] = arr[x];
    x++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: sure added description, although another answer was already accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `arr.length`. At every assignment, check to see if the length of the array is less than the value that you're currently at.